# If K-2SO is alone, then who is "we" here?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

On planet Eadu, Captain Andor and his team went to search Galen Erso
and leaving K-2SO alone in spoiled Imperial plane:

> K-2SO: What are they doing? If Cassian comes back, **we**'re leaving
> without them.

If K-2SO is alone, then who is "we" here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He is referring to himself and Cassian as 'we'. The 'them' that he is referring to are Jyn, Baze and Chirrut.

**Note that he's explicitly confirmed to be talking to himself in the [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novelization)).**

> The tragedy of K-2SO’s existence was this: The skills he most
> cherished were skills his rebel masters disdained; and the skills he
> considered crude and trivial were skills his masters were helpless to
> learn.
>
> Thus, his present circumstances: Instead of traveling to the research
> lab to manhandle, capture, restrain, and extract the scientist Galen
> Erso—a mission virtually requiring the talents of an Imperial security
> droid, and which might (if handled delicately) permit the exercise of
> multiple underutilized procedures hardcoded into K-2SO—he was rewiring
> a communications array and locating faults in each of eighty-four
> connectors by touch.
>
> Such a task required a bare minimum of computational power. K-2SO had
> more than enough to spare to listen to the goings-on in the cabin and
> observe the landscape from the half-buried cockpit viewport.
>
> He watched Jyn depart with disinterest. The woman had always verged on
> disrespectful toward him.
>
> He watched Baze and Chirrut depart with more robust disapproval. He
> posited an array of scenarios involving their separation from the
> U-wing, few of which ended in their continued well-being.
>
> “What are they doing?” he asked sharply.
>
> K-2SO was not a protocol droid, but he was designed for biological
> interaction. **He found that verbal discussion, even with himself,
> spurred his creativity.**
>
> He soon came to a solution he was satisfied with.
>
> “If Cassian comes back,” he said, “we’re leaving without them.”